# I want to retrieve user data and its value from firebase in android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have made an android app for home automation which uses fire base as a database. In app there is a login page and after successful login it goes to a blank activity where there is option menu to add dynamic button.But when user logout from their account the button which created dynamically does not save.
So i want to save that dynamic button for a particular user once they add the button and next time they login to their account button should be there.Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please add the code that you are using for that.

Comment: Please add the code your question.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: GridLayout ll = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
                ll.setOrientation(GridLayout.HORIZONTAL);
                final ImageButton myButton = new ImageButton(this);
                myButton.setLayoutParams(new GridLayout.LayoutParams());
                myButton.setImageResource(R.mipmap.bedroom_foreground);
                int d=myButton.getId();
                ll.addView(myButton);

      
                mdatabase.child(uid).push().child("Room").setValue(d);

Comment: I have created dynamic button from these code and i want it to save in UI

Comment: just for this purpose button shown you use shared preferences if data isnt your concern .

Comment: can you tell me how to store image button through shared preference.Do you have any code or any link related to it